# Deactivating hibernate debug logs (maven / deploy on weblogic)

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I'm dealing with a true nightmare here.
I received a ticket with the request to deactivate hibernate logging for services that are deployed in weblogic. Nothing can take these nasty debug logs away and they're flooding the system.

What I've tried:

- Added to log4j.properties:

  log4j.logger.org.hibernate = INFO, file
  log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
  log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
- Added to hibernate.properties:

  hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  hibernate.show_sql=false
  hibernate.format_sql=false
  hibernate.use_sql_comments=false

I will put the entire application to false if I could only get rid of these debug messages.

- Added an extra dependency to bridge between logback and log4j:

  org.slf4j
      slf4j-log4j12
      1.7.25
- Tried to exclude logback dependencies (which resulted in an error) / slf4j-api dependencies

We have quite a stack of dependencies, and included in the ear are:

- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- logback-classic-1.0.13.jar
- logback-core-1.0.13.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
- ...

  - And I also checked the weblogic repository to check if I there would be some repositories that get precedence over the ones packaged in the ear file.
  - Also tried the suggestion of @jay, to add a logback.xml file with the following content (without luck):

> ```
> <configuration>
>     <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="INFO" />
>     <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" />
>
>     <root level="INFO">
>         <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
>     </root>
> </configuration>
> ```

I am not sure if there may be some conflicting libraries here, or that it may be related to versioning. Or perhaps it may be related to Weblogic itself? Anyhow, any tips / pointers on how to resolve this matter are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough points to write a comment but i can post as an answer, consider this as a comment.

have you tried ?

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF

Comment: I could try that, but what if we would like to have INFO? I will give it a shot anyway.

Comment: after your tried INFO does the logger statements start with keyword "DEBUG" or "INFO" on each log statements ? I wonder if your properties are not getting applied.

Comment: It does mention "DEBUG", and the logs are going to the application log of the managed server. So yes, I do feel that nothing is having an actual effect.

Comment: looking at your dependencies your application may be using logback. do you see logback.xml file ? if not, add logback.xml and add those INFO statement over there. logback does not look at log4j.properties

Comment: I will try that. I hoped that the bridging library would fix this problem though (?). Also I should mention that the log4j.properties does work for the rest.